# Implementing a Web Service which sends/receives data via Form Get/Post

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I recently got a requirement to develop a new web service, and I'm not entirely sure how to approach it.

I'm familiar with normal WCF web services, where the url is something like

```
http://server/site/Service.svc/SomeMethod
```

that you can post XML/JSON to.

The new service is supposed to accept an HTML file post, where the content type is

```
multipart/form-data
```

From what I understand, the form contains fields, one of which contains a bunch of XML data which I want to parse. I will then respond by posting my own similar html file to a remote location.

I'm not completely sure how to begin with this. 
A WCF Service of some kind?
ASMX?
Or even an actual ASPX page that the client will post to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an .asmx file to create a web service and can use it through aspx pages